# AppEngine App Deploy gives "Failed to copy file."

Tags: google-app-engine, laravel-5, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I'm deploying a Laravel app to a fresh App Engine project. But I'm getting this error constantly. I tried creating a new project and deploying too.

```
╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
╠═ Uploading 9625 files to Google Cloud Storage             ═╣
╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
File upload done.
Updating service [default]...failed.                                                                                                                                    
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [3] Errors were encountered while copying files to App Engine.

Details: [
  [
    {
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ResourceInfo",
      "description": "Failed to copy file.",
      "resourceName": "https://storage.googleapis.com/staging.rsvp.appspot.com/df4bc71e8832337e997291648609c4e207b5aa55",
      "resourceType": "file"
    }
  ]
]
```

WHat is the problem here and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason for this issue was, I had some large size files ( > 30Mb ) in my project folder. I removed them and redeployed, it worked without an issue.

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly my problem.

Answer (score 2):

As OP already mentioned, the reason is large files. Here is how you can also find out which file is causing the problem.

If you have an error such as

```
Details: [
  [
    {
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ResourceInfo",
      "description": "Failed to copy file.",
      "resourceName": "https://storage.googleapis.com/staging.bemmu1-hrd.appspot.com/b463c152ee1498bd4d27c1ea67c7f8e82cb4b220",
      "resourceType": "file"
    }
  ]
]
```

Note the hash that appears in resourceName, in this case `"b463c152ee1498bd4d27c1ea67c7f8e82cb4b220"`.

Search for it in the most recent log file (mine was `/Users/bemmu/.config/gcloud/logs/2019.07.30/00.45.43.657001.log`) and you'll find it as part of a really long string, in my case:

```
...'templates/envato/images/arrangement.png': {'sourceUrl': 'https://storage.googleapis.com/staging.bemmu1-hrd.appspot.com/b463c152ee1498bd4d27c1ea67c7f8e82cb4b220'...
```

From this I could see that in my case the offending file was `arrangement.png`